# Computer boots to first screen and freezes

Tags: memory, bios, post

Computer boots to first screen and freezes. I reseated the ram and it boots until I shut down. On next reboot it freezes. Have replaced with new ram and it is still freezing until I reseat the ram. Puzzled.

Comment: Which do you count as the first screen?

Comment: The first screen should allow me to tab to  see post or press delete to access settings.Cannot do either.

Comment: Is this a new build, or was the computer working previously?

Comment: You need to be much more specific. There are an enormous number of troubleshooting steps to take from here so a bit more detail is required to help the community here to find an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Any more ideas for solving the problem? The computer will only boot once when I reseat the ram. It runs great in windows. If I restart or shut it down it will only go to the first screen till I reseat the ram again...... very frustrating.

Comment: Have your tried updating the bios?

Comment: can i ask something similar in this question?

Answer (score 0):

what is the first screen?

Have you tried removing the cmos battery and putting in back after a couple of minites?

you can also take the power cable out the back and push the power button a few times this fully discharges the pc then plug th epower back in and see what happens